# iOS: auto-correction on email input fields

Tags: ios, input-fields, auto-correct

In the app I am developing there is an email login and I have added auto-correction to the email input text field.

My thinking is that I have a text shortcut set up for @@ to be replaced by my email address. The auto correction does this. Also, iOS (I think) will eventually learn your email address and offer it for correction when necessary.

However, it has been suggested to remove this auto correction.

I was wondering if there is some best practice here that I can reference on whether I should enable/disable the auto-correction of the email input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean auto-suggestion? Or are you using auto-correct to validate an email format? That's probably not a good idea.

Many people have email addresses that do not correspond to English words, mostly due to the lack of spaces. If the application auto-corrects, Abby Normal may not notice that her carefully-input email address of "abbynormal" has been changed to "abnormal."

Better to use the HTML5 `input type="email"` Its purpose is to make sure that a properly-formed email address has been input.

On the other hand, if you mean auto-suggestion, where the browser remembers what you last input for that value, what are the reasons people are suggesting turning it off? Is it for security? Depending on your application's user base, that may not be an issue if they also have to input a password. The password is meant to bear the brunt of security, especially if a username is an email, which can easily be guessed or discovered.

Comment: Yeah, I meant auto-suggestion not validation. I'm on native iOS though not web. It was suggested to remove because of things like capitalising names in the email address or adding spaces to it etc... The thing with iOS is that it doesn't remember what was entered into a particular field but it does remember entries into a global iOS dictionary.